# PyTest: Auto delete temporary directory created with tmpdir_factory

Tags: python, testing, pytest, temporary-files

I'm trying to create a temporary directory with a specific name (eg, "data") for all tests within a module using PyTest's `tmpdir_factory` similar to the [tutorial](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html#the-tmpdir-factory-fixture):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def project_file(self, tmpdir_factory):
    return tmpdir_factory.mktemp("data")
```

I'm using the temporary directory in some tests within the module successfully. However, the directory still exists after running the tests and when I run them again, I get a failure because I cannot create a new temporary directory with name "data".

How can I automatically delete the temporary directory "data" after the pytest tests finish? The `tmpdir` argument creates temporary directory that is removed but it doesn't have a name and it only has function scope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can cleanup after the fixture is done like:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def project_file(self, tmpdir_factory):
    my_tmpdir = tmpdir_factory.mktemp("data")
    yield my_tmpdir 
    shutil.rmtree(str(my_tmpdir))
```

Comment: I changed to `yield` and added `shutil.rmtree()`, but the "temporary" directory still exists after the tests finish. Either the `rmtree` call is never reached or it doesn't work. As in the tutorial, I use the `project_file` as an argument for one of my test functions.

Comment: Using `shutil.rmtree('data')` instead of `shutil.rmtree(my_tmpdir)` solved the problem. Once the answer is adjusted, I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, `str(my_tmpdir)` also doesn't work. Only with `"data"` as parameter it did.

Comment: @CGFoX, if you are passing just the string `"data"` to rmtree, then something else is wrong with your code.  How are you using the `project_file` fixture?

Comment: You're right. I wasn't even properly using the tmpdir (which was created somewhere in my user's temp directory). Instead I was just creating a "data" directory indpendent of the tempdir_factory...